# Could not load type 'System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Before asking the question let me preface with the fact that I am new to asp.net and mvc. I come from Python, Node and PHP Frameworks.

All of my google searches are bringing up things about DisplayModes.Modes.Insert being an older syntax that was causing problems. But I'm also not using that anywhere.

I am getting this error in a MVC app. The app builds just fine, but only shows this:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider' from assembly
'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

I'm not using DisplayModeProvider anywhere.

Please let me know what other information is needed to help me solve this. I'm kinda shooting in the dark...

Comment: You are missing the System.Web.WebPages assembly when you deployed your application.  Are you running this through Visual Studio or did you deploy to a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar error from a [blog posting](http://tkntips.blogspot.com/2012/05/could-not-load-type-systemwebwebpagesdi.html) explaining that it has to do with differing versions of the System.Web.WebPages and MVC 4 Developer Preview/Beta.

I would recommend you do a clean install the MVC version that you are using and ensure that all of your .dll versions are correct in your project.  Though you are not calling DisplayModes anywhere, that does not mean that another dependency (.dll reference) in your project is not.