# publishing ASP.Net MVC 4 Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have a solution that contains 4 class library all with .Net 4 and a MVC 4 project. it's working when I run project on Visual Studio, I also published project and ran it under my local machine IIS and it worked perfectly.
But the problem is when I run my published project in server I get this error:

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider' from assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

I looked into following links but I couldn't solve this issue yet:
http://tkntips.blogspot.com/2012/05/could-not-load-type-systemwebwebpagesdi.html
[Could not load type 'System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModeProvider'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215206/could-not-load-type-system-web-webpages-displaymodeprovider)

In link above one says :

> just remove the above DLLs from the project bin directory (using
>   "Clean" in Visual Studio didn't seem to do this for some reason), then
>   rebuild the project: the above files don't need to be in the bin
>   directory - the GAC seems to be able to find the correct versions all
>   on its own.

Does it mean, the guy suggest to delete DLLs? then how my project reference to MVC or other assemblies?

---

I also made an empty MVC 4 Project, Published and I still get same error...

---

**Update #1:** Assembly versions

- System.Web.Mvc 4.0.20710.0
- System.Web.WebPages 2.0.20710.0
- System.Web.Razor 2.0.20715.0
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment 2.0.20710.0
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor 2.0.20710.0

I don't know if `System.Web.WebPages` should be same version as `System.Web.Mvc` too, if yes where/how I find the correct version?

Comment: Can you have a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215206/could-not-load-type-system-web-webpages-displaymodeprovider and verify that all of your assemblies have correct version and all of them are available on your deployment server ?

Comment: @Drakkonite Updated my question with assembly versions

Comment: Did you check to see if your assembly property "Copy To Local" was set to "True"? If MVC isn't installed on the server, then these DLLs need to be copied with your deployment.

Comment: Install asp.net mvc on the server machine its not installed there

Comment: `System.Web.Mvc`, `System.Web.WebPages` "Copy to Local" property was set to True by default. 
However I installed MVC 4 in server, too bad problem still remains :(
FYI, I made an empty MVC 3 project and it worked as it should be...

Comment: @mhesabi Could you please use this tutorial to enable Fusionlog ? [enable Fusion Log](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) Then check if you are not missing any assemblies. Do you see any InnerExceptions in StackTrace with this error ?